# Node.js when sending POST request with base64 decoded characters, invalid characters error appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, request

I am trying to send POST request with base64 decoded string, however I get invalid characters error.

I have this block to generate base64 decoded string:

```
var domain = "domain.com";
var decoded = Buffer.from("x3abaARV"+domain+"1cYNYtk", 'base64').toString('ascii');
```

and then I sent POST request using `request` module from npm:

```
var headers = {
    ip: "10.100.0.420",
    key: decoded,
    domain: domain
}
var options = {
      url: 'http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/example.json',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
  }

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
...
```

which returns:

> ypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
>       at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:358:11)
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:86:14)
>       at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
>       at Request.start (/home/kuno/code/aviokarte-web/node_modules/request/request.js:744:32)
>       at Request.end (/home/kuno/code/aviokarte-web/node_modules/request/request.js:1435:10)
>       at end (/home/kuno/code/aviokarte-web/node_modules/request/request.js:566:14)
>       at Immediate. (/home/kuno/code/aviokarte-web/node_modules/request/request.js:580:7)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)

How do I properly set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the value of `decoded`, you will find that there are non-printable characters, which are not allowed in HTTP header values. You will need to use some kind of binary-safe encoding (such as base64 or URL/"percent" encoding) for that kind of data.